# Can we import a python package from one environment to other

Tags: python, anaconda, miniconda

Can we import any particular python package from one environment to other in miniconda.
And, how to install a python package in python 2 environment when it needs python 3.

Comment: do pip freeze>requirements.txt in old environment, then do pip install -r requirements.txt in the new environment.

Comment: Regarding the later part of your question: you don't, it won't work. It's time to upgrade your projects and environments to Python 3 or retire them.

Answer (score 0):

No, packages are installed for a specific virtual environment, and are not shared. You will need to re-install the packages for other environments.

`Conda` (and `pip`) may cache the downloaded materials though, and re-use the zip files.